# A SQL query for the retrieval of result based on input month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

My requirement is to input the Redemption month and list the tickets that has been scanned double or more.

For example Ticket No. T1 has been scanned  2 times under pickup,only once under `PickupOutforDelivery` and 2 times under Delivery.

**Result needed like this:**

[image]

How can I write a query to get the result like this?

Tried:

```
SELECT 
    Ticket, 
    COUNT(Scantype = 0) AS Pickup,
    COUNT(Scantype = 1) AS PickupOutforDelivery,
    COUNT(Scantype = 2) AS Delivery 
FROM 
    Scans
GROUP BY 
    Ticket, ScanType 
HAVING
    (Pickup > 1 OR PickupOutforDelivery > 1 OR Delivery > 1) 
    OR (Pickup >= 1 AND PickupOutforDelivery >= 1)
ORDER BY 
    Ticket
```

Result 
[image]

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are different products with different language syntax. Please pick the One you're actually using.  (Also, please be clear on the datatype you're using for the RedemptionMonth, and please Please don't let it be that you're using text/strings?)

Comment: @MatBailie I'm using SQL server and I would like to get a query to retrieve the data. The datatype for RedemptionMonthis varchar.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far

Comment: @PeterSmith

SELECT TicketNo, COUNT(Scantype=0) AS Pickup,COUNT(Scantype=1) AS PickupOutforDelivery,COUNT(Scantype=2) AS Delivery FROM Scans GROUP BY TicketNo, ScanType HAVING(Pickup >1 OR PickupOutforDelivery>1 OR Delivery>1) OR (Pickup>=1 AND PickupOutforDelivery>=1)ORDER BY TicketNo

Comment: That's not SQL Server, that's MySQL. Make your mind up.

Comment: @MatBailie ok..I'm trying with the mysql console of XAMP.

Comment: @vyshakh Then fix your tags. And any additional information that is requested should be added to your question, not posted as in a comment. In addition, SQL does not produce "pretty" results as you depict. You should do that sort of formatting in whatever consumes your resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that RedemptionMonth has a datatype of DATE (which is clearly required); the following query will give you the result you want, except the "cosmetic" part (breaking by year month for the report part) that you have to do on your application:

```
SELECT YEAR(RedemptionMonth) AS [YEAR], MONTH(RedemptionMonth) AS [MONTH], TicketNo, 
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ScanName = 'Pickup' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS Pickup,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ScanName = 'PickupOutForDelivery' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS PickupOutForDelivery ,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ScanName = 'Delivery' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS Delivery
FROM   [Table 1] AS T1
       JOIN [Table 2] AS T2 
          ON T1.ScanType = T2.ScanType
GROUP  BY YEAR(RedemptionMonth) AS [YEAR], MONTH(RedemptionMonth) AS [MONTH], TicketNo
```

Comment: can you say the use of COALESCE? Can we use this in mySQL too??

Comment: Have you checked `mySQL` and `COALESCE` with Google? That answers your question.

Comment: SELECT TicketNo, COUNT(Scantype=0) AS Pickup,COUNT(Scantype=1) AS PickupOutforDelivery,COUNT(Scantype=2) AS Delivery FROM Scans GROUP BY TicketNo, ScanType HAVING(Pickup >1 OR PickupOutforDelivery>1 OR Delivery>1) OR (Pickup>=1 AND PickupOutforDelivery>=1)ORDER BY TicketNo

Tried this..

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the numeric value of `scanType`, no `JOIN` is needed.  So, the only fix is needed for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Ticket, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Scantype = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Pickup,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Scantype = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PickupOutforDelivery,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Scantype = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Delivery 
FROM Scans
WHERE redemptionMonth = 'Jan-21'
GROUP BY Ticket 
HAVING Pickup > 1 OR
       PickupOutforDelivery > 1 OR
       Delivery > 1 OR 
       (Pickup >= 1 AND PickupOutforDelivery >= 1)
ORDER BY Ticket;
```

Note that you can add `redemptionMonth` to the `GROUP BY` (and `SELECT`) to get the results for each month.

If `redemptionMonth` is really a date and not a string, then define the time period using a range of dates:

```
WHERE redemptionMonth >= '2021-01-01' AND
      redemptionMonth < '2021-02-01'
```